# I need to open an image as popup Onclicking same image in Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
    <td><a [href]="scan.domainDetails.screenshot"
                           *ngIf="scan.domainDetails&&scan.domainDetails.screenshot"
                           target="_blank"><img
                            [src]="scan.domainDetails.screenshot"
                            matTooltip="View Image"  matTooltipPosition="above"
                            style="border-radius:3px;height: 80px; width: 100px" 
                            class="image"></a>
    </td>
```

This is html code when i click on image it opens in new tab and display the image.Now i need to display like when i click on image it should open as popup and close in angular.
Thanks

Comment: Make use of the Angular Material UI and look for the Dialog component. This component will pop up when activated and you can add an image to it.

Comment: instead of dialog component can we directly open image

Comment: Web does not have a functionality to just "open an image". You have to make that yourself and instead of doing a lot of work yourself. You can use an Material UI to make your life easier.